# Find extremums of complicated function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find max and min of this function:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^{2} \sqrt{x^{2}-1}}{2x^2-1}$$

I made a replacement $$t = \sqrt{x^{2} - 1}, x^{2} = t^{2} + 1$$:

$$f(t) = \frac{t^3 + t}{2t^{2}+1}$$

I found a derivative:

$$f(t)^{'} = \frac{2t^{4} + t^{2} + 1}{(2t^{2}+1)^{2}}=0$$

So my discriminant is negative and i can't find roots, though they exist. How to find them?

Comment: If you replaced x on RHS, it should be done on LHS too, right?

Comment: After your replacement, you will get $f(\sqrt{t^2+1})$ and not $f(t)$.

Comment: The first derivative is of no use in this problem. You should rather look at the endpoints of the domain of $f$

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- what are RHS and LHS

Comment: Left hand side and right hand side